# Tutorials for Code Obfuscation in C

Tags: c, obfuscation

I am fascinated by the way people obfuscate their code (mostly, C) (examples here : http://ioccc.org/) and would like to learn the various techniques for the same. I have been told of a book, "Obfuscated C and other Mysteries", but I am not able to get that book. 
Are there any tutorials or books that give hints on this topic? 
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think a generic technique can exist for this... One has to be creative.

Comment: Lots of obfuscation over on [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The best you can do is read the comments of the author of the programs on IOCCC. They describe how they manage to obfuscate their code. Here are a few pointers:

### Short and meaningless identifiers

Because `a=aaa*aa;` will always be more obfuscated than `result = value * factor;`

In order to have short identifiers, obfuscators tend to even `#define` many things.

### Reversed array indexing

You just have to remember that `var[3]` and `3[var]` are equivalent.

### Digraphs and trigraphs

`if(a< <:b+aa??))??<f();%>`

should be less readable than:

`if (a < (b+aa)) { f(); }`

### Look-alike characters

Sometimes, it's hard to tell appart `l`, `1` and `I` or `o`, `0` and `O`. For example, if you write `10l`, I bet everyone will read `101` instead.

### Coding style guidelines

Generally speaking, just try to find good coding guidelines and to try to *violate them all*. Those documents that you could find anywhere on the web could help you more than most things and would allow you not to buy anything.

Here are some links:

- [How to write unmaintainable code](https://github.com/Droogans/unmaintainable-code/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Oh yeah, recursive files inclusion with X-macros to generate some code in a totally obfusated way.

Comment: @Morwenn: it doesn't need to be anything as heavy as X-macros - you'll often see plain old macro definitions in obfuscated code entries. For example, redefining a keyword can make reading a program quite painful: `#define char k['a']`

Comment: @MichaelBurr But I already talked about `#defin`ing stuff in my second point :)

Comment: @Morwenn: I see. I missed it because it wasn't a 'top level' item.

Comment: @Morwenn I knew the main points you have mentioned. Was looking for specifics. Thanks anyways. Nice link, btw. :)

Answer (score 7):

Morwenn's answer nicely covers obfuscation of *syntax*. But there is another level, and that is *semantic* obfuscation. Consider that the oft-mentioned Turing Machine has the same computational power as any other programming language (ignoring considerations of input and output). In fact all of the various models of computation have sibling models with equivalent power.

For example, a string `char s[N]` can be considered a mapping from indices to characters, so any string can be represented instead by a function which always delivers the appropriate character when called with a specified index `char f(int i)`. Now read [this](http://www.korokithakis.net/posts/printing-hello-world-using-curve-fitting/). Crazy, right?